# When will this object be disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, garbage-collection

I am using RestSharp to send requests to an Elastic Search cluster, I'm just curious as to when this object will be declared out of scope and collected by the GC.

```
request.AddBody(new Record
{
     pty_name_prefix = drow[3].ToString(),
     pty_surname = drow[4].ToString(),
     pty_name_suffix = drow[5].ToString(),
     pty_forename = drow[6].ToString(),
     pty_address = drow[7].ToString(),
     pty_full_name = drow[6] + " " + drow[4]
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: "Disposed" (from your question title) and "garbage collected" are entirely different things - and objects don't *have* a scope, so they can't go out of one...

Comment: @JonSkeet Appears I have some further reading to do... When will this object no longer exist? If I am looping round a block of code creating a new HTTP request with a new object of type Record as the body and executing the request async, when will the object be GC?

Comment: I'd *hope* that it would be eligible for GC (which isn't the same as actually collected) when the request had been sent - but do you even know this is a problem?

Comment: If you mean the `new Record` then I'm pretty sure it exists only between ( and ); and so as it's not a variable then it doesn't actually have a scope in this case; when it gets gc'd is pretty much an unknown...aaand I see just as I'm typing that Jon Skeet is here so by definition this comment is already out of scope ha ha

Comment: @JonSkeet In honesty, no. Essentially what I am doing is sending a large amount of database records to Elastic Search via HTTP, obviously. The application sends around 1000 records per second to the ES cluster but then gradually declines to around 20/30 per second, I'm looking at all possibilities such as disabling anti-virus etc but I'm trying to find why it slows so much. Am I exhausting something?

Comment: A guess would be that your server throttles your connection because your a flooding it with requests.

Comment: @NSmeef, have you profiled that code to see what parts of it take the most time over N iterations? Something like the ANTS performance profiler will pretty much show you how the various parts of that loop perform over time - you might be surprised to find that it's some other part that's holding things up...might even be some kind of request throttling going on (on your side or the server's side)

Comment: @StephenByrne I've bought ANT's but I didn't get the chance to run it when initially starting the application, so I will definitely be using it once I rerun. I'll post back some results and some more code when I get some further details.

Comment: @NSmeef, excellent - if I had a euro for every time ANTS has saved me grief over stuff like this, I'd have...well, I'd have about 2 euros, but you know what I mean :)

Comment: Ok, I ran the program and just selected the first 10,000 rows and ran as normal. What I did notice was that I had a `Console.Writeline` to tell me the time elapsed and this was being written to console before the application has finished all the HTTP POST requests, which is pretty obvious as its executing the requests asynchronously. Are there any observations to be taken from this? Should I perhaps reduce the queue on the `ExecuteAsync` by having several of these to reduce load?

Answer (score 3):

It is important to realize that Garbage Collection **may never happen**.

As long as your machine has enough memory, the GC may simply decide *"everything is running fine, I don't need to collect old memory"*.

As a result, we can only talk about objects being "eligible for garbage collection".  Once eligible, GC *may* happen at any point in the future (or may never happen at all).

Comment: hey, just curious why is this GC has been implemented this way that we cannot say that when it gonna be happen ?

Comment: The Collector takes up CPU time and resources to do Garbage Collection.  Why should it bother to take up your resources just to collect a handful of bytes on a machine that may still have Gigabytes free?  Read [**this article**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx)

Comment: You can call GC.Collect() to force garbage collection, but it would be unusual for this to actually be a benefit.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there are no valid references on the object, then its memory is *available* for garbage collection.  Read MSDN [GC Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.aspx) and [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection: Generations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx#generations) for background info.